# Compare size of values in columns which are in kbs, mbs and gbs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare each row with its previous row size, lets say if first row have 6kb size and 2nd row has 2kb size. if second row of dataframe has 50% less size than the previous one then that row should be printed.

following is my dataframe,

```
    size     number     key      date
0  120 K    12345     Hello     20181002
1  119 K    12345     No        20181001
2  30 K     12345     Hello     20181003
3  90 K     12345     No        20181003
4  150 K    12345     Hello     20181004
5  180 M    12345     No        20181005
6  70 M     12345     Hello     20181006
```

in above dataframe 2nd row compare with 1st and the difference in not less than 50% then it will ignore, but 3rd row size is less than 50% of 2nd row so it will print 3rd row
same for 6th row will be print as it is less than 50% of size.

Comment: I'll be frank. Asking a new question on StackOverflow should not be your first port of call any time you hit any snag when coding. This is your third question today, while some of them are interesting, this one really could be easily determined by constructing a column after applying `df.shift`. Your previous question's answer was `df.reindex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to translate the `size` column with `K`, `M`, `G`, etc. to their corresponding values scaled up by the magnitude symbols, as follows:

`K` converted to `e+03` in scientific notation

`M` converted to `e+06` in scientific notation

`G` converted to `e+09` in scientific notation

**(supports `integer` as well as `float` numbers in *any number of decimal places*)**

Then, convert the text in scientific notation to float type, followed by casting to integer for final required format, as follows:

```
size_val = df['size'].replace({' ': '', 'K': 'e+03', 'M': 'e+06', 'G': 'e+09'}, regex=True).astype(float).astype(int)
```

Then, use `df.loc` to filter the rows with size ratio of current row and previous row (with getting values of previous row by [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)):

```
df.loc[(size_val / size_val.shift()) < 0.5]
```

**Result:**

```
   size  number    key      date
2  30 K   12345  Hello  20181003
6  70 M   12345  Hello  20181006
```

***Translated values of `size`*** (in `size_val`) ***are the actual values*** (translated from texts to integers) ***scaled up by the magnitude symbols:***

```
print(size_val)


0       120000
1       119000
2        30000
3        90000
4       150000
5    180000000
6     70000000
Name: size, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Nice, but I think `pd.eval` is an extra step in this case as you can directly replace the string with required digits and change to an int without having to evaluate the string.

Comment: @DavidErickson  In this particular data, it is.  But if the data could have decimal points of various decimal places, we can't simply do that.  I used this which could handle more general cases of supporting decimal points.  Anyway, agree that if only have integer values, we can simplify it.

Comment: @anky  Edited to without using `pd.eval`.  Now use only `.replace()` and `.astype()` for value conversion.  Support both float and integer figures in `size` column too.   :-)

Comment: @DavidErickson  Revised without using `pd.eval` now. Use only `.replace()` and `.astype()` for value conversion. Support both integer and float figures with various decimal places too :-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need to transform the string to an integer first according to "K" or "M"? You can do this by creating a `size_dict` and then comparing to the row prior with `shift()`:

```
size_dict = {' K' : '', ' M' : '000'}
size = df['size'].replace(size_dict, regex=True).astype(int)
df[(size.shift()*.5).gt(size)]
Out[1]: 
   size  number    key      date
2  30 K   12345  Hello  20181003
6  70 M   12345  Hello  20181006
```

Comment: and what should i do for G(gb)

Comment: G would be 6 zeros